# Pentaho PDI on Ubuntu 18

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration, pentaho-design-studio

I have Pentaho setup and running on Windows 10, I am planning to migrate to Ubuntu. Has anyone setup Pentaho on Ubuntu 18.04? If yes, what is the configuration you are using? Pentaho documentation says mentions Ubuntu 14 and 16 to be used and are there any issues in particular on Ubuntu 18?

Comment: Hello! Probably this question belongs to askUbuntu stack, instead of stackoverflow.

Comment: @AndyTheos probably yes. posting there as well. Thanks!